# Polynomial regression with microlensing parameters

Tags: computational-physics, software, data-analysis, gravitational-lensing, weak-lensing

As a hobbyist I would like to learn more about microlensing by exploring some data and performing some simple regression analysis. Based on the exoplanet archive of microlensing planets

[https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/TblView/nph-tblView?app=ExoTbls&config=M](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/TblView/nph-tblView?app=ExoTbls&config=ML)

I have identified some independent variables/parameters that I thought might be possible to use in a polynomial regression analysis. I am not sure how these parameters relate to each other. Could someone identify some relationship from the given parameters?

```
pl_massj: Planet Mass [Jupiter mass]
pl_orbsmax: Planet-star Projected Semi-major Axis [au]
st_mass: Lens Mass [Solar mass]
sy_dist: Lens Distance [pc]
ml_dists: Source Distance [pc]
ml_tsepmin: Time of Lens-source Minimum Separation [days]
ml_xtimeein: Einstein Crossing Time [days]
ml_radsnorm: Normalized Source Angular Radius (10^-3)
ml_massratio: Planet-star Mass Ratio (10^-4)
ml_angstlax: Source Trajectory-lens Axis Angle [rad]
ml_magis: Source I-band [mag]
```